# Adaptive Payments API - Chained Refunds

Tags: paypal

I am interested in using Adaptive Payments API to setup a simple service site where I act as an agent between a seller and a buyer.

Lets say the buyer purchases a product for $100, I take a $20 cut and the $80 goes to the seller. Now lets say the buyer is unhappy and wants a refund.

How does the system actually work this, with myself holding the Paypal business account if I issue a refund will it refund both my $20 and the $80 from the sellers account? Or does the buyer have to request a refund from the seller directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seller need to grant you with permission to make a refund on behalf of him, so that you could call the Refund API . You may refer to the below page for more details .

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/